# Simplify a complex function .

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

What's the meaning of "simplify" using $z=x+iy$ when i have the functions $e^{z^2}$, $e^{iz}$ and $e^{1/z}$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ any hint or skecth of procedure to follow?

I've tried and I arive to $e^{z^2}=e^{xz}\cdot e^{iy(z)}$ but I think that this is wrong... Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First simplify the argument of the exponential, then use Euler's formula. Example:

If $z = x +iy$ then $e^{z^2} = e^{x^2-y^2 + i2xy} = e^{x^2-y^2}(\cos(2xy) +i \sin(2xy)).$

Comment: So that's it the author means with "simplify"? I feel so dumb... because I think that we must arrive to a "singular or unexpected" expression...

Comment: how can $e^{z^2}$ be singular? It is the composition of two functions which are entire. What do you mean by "unexpected"?

Comment: not singular o unexpected in formal sense... figurative, like amazing result!

Comment: @Ragnar1204 If the book is asking for something that subjective I would probably discuss it with the instructor. The only function with a singularity anywhere in $\mathbb{C}$ is the last, but even this is analytic everywhere on $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank's by the advice... I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Ragnar1204 It's what SE's for :-)